# Break when the first exception occurs in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm using VS 2019, I'm wondering if there is a way to break when an exception is thrown, even if it is caught.
I can't manage to find out where the exception is really thrown since there are many exception handlers and the exception pop-up comes up when the stack is no longer indicating anything.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Also a wild guess, but are you aware of breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go into the exception settings of Visual studio (you can easily find it with the search bar)

And then you check the exception category that is needed (CLR for example)

[image]

Uncheck it after when it is no more needed (or use the restore default button)

Comment: I would be careful unchecking the CLREs, as you mentioned using the reset button is usually the best way of reverting.